# Pass 2 parameters from AJAX to Python script

Tags: jquery, python-3.x

I want to pass 2 parameters from jQuery AJAX to python script. I found that I need to use Flask library. Is there any other way other than Flask?

Comment: Are you asking how to consume 2 parameters in python or send 2 from ajax?

Comment: Consume the parameters sent from Ajax in python

Comment: Please be more specific. Are you passing the parameters via POST or GET,  have you take a look to at the documentation of Flask? http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#a-minimal-application

Comment: I am passing parameters via POST from Ajax which executes a python script. i have a method in python which should accept these two parameters  and perform some operations. Yeah i have  looked at that document.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as you've provided no code examples.